# Combine if conditions in Python

Tags: python

Does this exist in Python? I want to combine an If statement that is very repetitive.

```
# ORIGINAL IF STATEMENT
if a < 100 and b < 100 and c < 100:
    #pass

# I KNOW THIS IS WRONG, I JUST WANT TO KNOW IF THERE IS A WAY TO MAKE THE IF CONDITION SHORTER
if [a,b,c] < 100:
    #pass
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(item < 100 for item in [a, b, c]):
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the built-in [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
if max(a, b, c) < 100:
```